# Call WebService in C# and read data (Dictionary<string, object>)

Tags: c#, web-services, dictionary

Here is a basic question, but after calling my WebService (hosted in another server) in a MasterPage code-behind, I'm not sure how to read the response, which is a dictionary (string, object).

WebService call :

```
string completeUrl = "http://server/PublicServices/MyWebService.asmx/GetAppInfos";
completeUrl = string.Concat(completeUrl, "?login={0}&site_guid={1}");
completeUrl.Replace(login, site_guid);

System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(completeUrl);
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd(); // How to get response as a Dictionary<string, object> ?

reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

WebService :

```
[WebMethod(Description = "GetAppInfos")]
[ScriptMethod]
public Dictionary<string, object> GetAppInfos(string login, string site_guid)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> appInfos = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    appInfos["a"] = "b";
    appInfos["c"] = "d";
    return appInfos;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: What streaming context does the webservice use? JSON, XML, Binary?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are doing your web service call in the Code behind. You should add a Web Reference for your ASMX Service. This can be done by right clicking on the Service References folder from within Solution Explorer. From there select Add Service Reference and fill in the form.

Once this is Done you can simply use a using statement as follows.

```
Using(var myService = New **WebReferenceNamespace**.MyWebServiceSoapClient)
{
      var responseFromServer = myService.GetAppInfos(login, site_guid);
}
```

You will need to replace `**WebReferenceNamespace**` with the namespace you give your service reference. The Default will be `ServiceReference1` for your first service reference with the number incrementing for each one you add. I suggest giving it a meaningful name.

**Also I should mention It is recommended that if you are doing new development to switch over to using WCF webservices.**